# PHP array_diff weirdness

Tags: php

This is such a simple problem but the PHP doc does not explain why it is happening.

I have this code:

```
var_dump($newattributes); var_dump($oldattributes);
var_dump(array_diff($newattributes, $oldattributes));
```

For briefity I am going to omit large parts of the structure I am actually using (since each is 117 elements long) and cut to the case.

I have one array called `$newattributes` which looks like:

```
array(117){
    // Lots of other attributes here
    ["deleted"] => int(1)
}
```

And another called `$oldattributes` which looks like:

```
array(117){
    // Lots of other attributes here
    ["deleted"] => string(1) "0"
}
```

Which looks different right? According to `array_diff`: no. The output I get from `array_diff` is:

```
array(0) { }
```

I have read the documentation page however it says:

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

And I am not sure how "1" can object equal "0".

So am I seeing some caveat with `array_diff` I didn't take into consideration?

Comment: Good question, clear, well asked and not too long and too much code. More people should do it like this! +1

Comment: This shouldn't happen, and indeed [it does not for me](http://ideone.com/jDeUd).

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the test, I'll look more into my PHP build

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem might reside in the fact that you are using associative arrays : you should try and use the following for associative arrays : [array_diff_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
<?php 
    $newattributes = array(
       "deleted" => 1 
    );

    $oldattributes = array(
       "deleted" => "0" 
    );

    $result = array_diff_assoc($newattributes, $oldattributes);

    var_dump($result);
?>
```

result :

```
   array(1) {
       ["deleted"]=>
       int(1)
   }
```

Comment: you are welcome :) PHP is a very forgiving language, knowing the right functions at times usually does the right trick.

Answer (score 2):

It *does* happen to me too (when there are more values than one)

```
$new = array('test' => true, 'bla' => 'test' 'deleted' => 1);
$old = array('test' => true, 'deleted' => '0');
```

For a *full* array_diff you need to make some extra work, because in default it returns a [relative complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement)

Try this:

```
array_diff(array_merge($new, $old), array_intersect($new, $old))
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [bla] => test
    [deleted] => 0
)
```

Comment: Indeed that works thanks, I have taken the other answer as the marked one since it doesn't need the merge or intersect but +1 for being first with a working and backing math, this is prolly what PHP does when comparing assoc

Comment: That work around does the same as : array_diff_assoc() . great find though :) +1

Comment: Yeahh, `array_diff_assoc` obviously is way easier, didn't know that. SO is a great tool to learn extra things :)